# Oracle: Error when executing query

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, hibernate3

I have a table `SyncTokenLock` that has column `lockName` that is of CLOB type. When I run following query from SQLDeveloper -

```
select * from SyncTokenLock where 
lockName='com.vmware.horizon.datastore.impl.ProvisioningStateDataServiceImpl';
```

I get following exception -

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

I get similar error when this query is executed through Hibernate (3.6.10) against Oracle 11g. Hibernate throws following exception -

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Any idea what could the reason be.

Comment: It seems the error is because Oracle does not allow `CLOB` datatype in where clause. Not sure. Could anyone confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, you can't use equality with a CLOB in the WHERE clause. But you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM SyncTokenLock 
 WHERE dbms_lob.substr(lockName, 100) = 
           'com.vmware.horizon.datastore.impl.ProvisioningStateDataServiceImpl';
```

Does your column *really* need to be a CLOB? Are you expecting values over 4000 characters? If not, use a VARCHAR2.

Comment: Even I am not sure if I need it to be CLOB. I have legacy code that runs on PostgreSQL. I need to add support of Oracle. This column was specified as VARCHAR(4096), so used CLOB when designing schema for Oracle. As of now I changed the column type to VARCHAR2(4000) from CLOB to make it work. Not sure how foolproof is that. Your solution would work against Oracle but not against PostgreSQL. I am using hibernate to do the database talking for Oracle and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the equal sign, you may use `like`:

```
select * from SyncTokenLock where lockName like 'com.vmware.horizon.datastore.impl.ProvisioningStateDataServiceImpl';
```